# Calling function directly in functional component body in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component and some function is called directly in the body (that function changes the state && it's needed to be run each render). Is it 100% okay, or could it cause bugs?

```
const myFunc = (setMyState, ...) => {
    ...
    setMyState(...)
}

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(...)
    myFunc(setMyState, ...)
    return(<div>some content...</div>)
}
```

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cause an infinite loop. This is why:

1. component renders first time
2. function updates component state
3. component renders because of state update
4. function runs again and updates component again
5. etc

You can definitely avoid this by using if-statements inside the function, but the best way to update a component state is either by user input/api calls or props updating(your case I suppose)

The best way to do that in my opinion is using the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: **"You can definitely avoid this by using if-statements inside the function"**. I agree that the question needs more details, but in general this is an anti-pattern

Comment: You call this function that has `setState` as an argument a hook? Really? This function as said by OP is used to update component state.. and yes it is an anti-pattern to pass `setState` to functions outside of React's scope

Comment: (I don't get notification you replied if you don't @ ping me.) I somehow managed to **miss the part of the question where they said it set state.** o_O My bad!! :-)